# Purpose of supports-screens in Manifest

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have 2 scenarios

Scenario 1: The manifest file having the below mentioned tags

```
<supports-screens            
android:xlargeScreens="true" 
android:largeScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:smallScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Scenario 2: The manifest file does not have the supports-screens tag.

Could you please explain how this scenario works ?  I mean the pros and cons of the 2 scenario.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
<supports-screens>
```

Lets you specify the screen sizes your application supports and enable screen compatibility mode for screens larger than what your application supports. **It's important that you always use this element in your application to specify the screen sizes your application supports.**

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html

Check the description part in the above link. If you read the description part it should answer your question.

As a side note check this link also http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: what happens if we do not have this tag in manifest. I could see my app still running fine

Comment: it will but there is reason why you should mention it and that is exactly described int he description part

Comment: Thanks, Just one more confirmation needed. So with the above tags xlargeScreens,largeScreens,normalScreens,smallScreens set to true I can run in all possible device sizes ?

Comment: you will have to define layouts fro those screen sizes. its like telling android that app supports screen sizes mentioned.

Comment: Even if you are not providing different screen for different layouts, it will pick the best suited one. But my only concern here is the google play uses this details to list the App for different devices based on the supports-screens. So in this context, will this app be available for all the devices ?

Comment: @iappmaker read the highlighted part of the answer above and keep in mind the word important.

Comment: Could you please confirm this one.  On setting the tags  (xlargeScreens,largeScreens,normalScreens,smallScreens) to true google play will list the app in all android devices. Am I correct ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html#compatibility